# How to open a .onion site?

Tags: onion-services, help

I  heard of the Tor browser from friend and downloaded it.

I'm  curious to see what exists on the .onion sites but all the ones I tried shows me an error message telling me that there is a connection problem.

I wonder if I have properly configure Tor and if not, how can I make it correctly?

Comment: [Here](https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/) is the address of the DuckDuckGo hidden service.<br/>
I've confirmed that it's working. If you can't connect to this then it's likely you have a configuration issue.<br/>
If you download and use the Tor browser bundle you shouldn't have any configuration issues. [Here](http://deepwikizpkrt67e.onion/index.php/Main_Page) is a link to a page containing links to other .onion sites.
While it contains active links I can't guarantee that it's trustable.

Comment: I've configured firefox to use my proxies dns when using tor. The new firefox versions his is done in the configuration. Without it , your browser attempt to resolve the hidden service address with your normal DNS (isp's or googles) and that will not happen. Try this http://jermsmit.com/configure-firefox-to-use-ssh-tunnel-for-dns/

Comment: In my experience it just depends on the site; some work some don't.
This is probably do to the site no longer existing so just keep trying! **JpR**

Comment: Tor, if configured, will automatically run .onion links on its browser.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the dns function of tor. In `torrc`, add the line

```
DNSPort 53
```

If you use unix, you will also need to add the line

```
user tor
```

to torrc and run tor as root, because it needs to bind to port 53.

And configure your operating system to use `localhost` as DNS server.

There are also other ways, such as using a caching dns server.

Comment: Is this really necessary? I run the Tor Browser with the default configuration, and I can access Onion services just fine.

Comment: Agreed with the last comment. It's likely this is just the problem of the hidden service no longer existing, as per one of the comments on the question itself.